# Set path in Visual Foxpro

Tags: visual-foxpro

I want to set path in Visual Foxpro. In such a way that I  want to keep exe file on local machine and data\tables on server. How can I do so?

Comment: Reworded for clarity, Better title.

Answer (score 1):

I personally have never liked using SET PATH, especially if you have many "paths" that your application is expecting to use..  If you have a given table / file in multiple locations that are visible with multiple paths that qualify, you may be getting the wrong table, but you won't necessarily know it since the application just runs as normal, finds a table and continues.

Instead, I would suggest one of a few things.  Yes, have your application on each user's local machine, but have the person's shortcut have the "START IN" folder pointing to the path on the server where your data is.  This way, your application will BE in the folder where the data resides and processes without issue.  If no data is on the local machine, during your startup, you could add a messagebox about ... hey... your shortcut should be set to "Start In" setting to X:\SomeShareOnServer\MyVFPDataPath...

If not that, then another avenue I have used is to have your application during startup, add a property to the "_Screen" object which will NEVER loose scope, and set that property to the path you have the data located such as...

```
_Screen.AddProperty( "cDataPath" )
_Screen.cDataPath = "X:\SomeShareOnServer\MyVFPDataPath\"
```

Then, in your code, any of your opening tables or SQL queries, use the path variable PLUS the table... something like

```
if not used( "SomeTable" )
   select 0
   use ( _Screen.cDataPath + "SomeTable" )
endif
```

if doing a query, use similar approach

```
select ST.* ;
   from ( _Screen.cDataPath + "SomeTable" ) ST ;
   where ST.SomeID = 123;
   into cursor C_TmpResult readwrite
```

So, although the second option may take more effort, especially on an existing application, the first option to make sure the "Start In" path is where the data is might help.

Again, this is my suggestion as I hate chasing down ambiguous -- sometimes it works, but not others.  If I can't find a file, I WANT TO KNOW about it and fail outright.

Your call, your app, your environment.  But if you DO use the "SET PATH" command, you might want to make sure you use the ADDITIVE command, just in case there are other settings, such as pointing to the a path for forms, classes, report folders... You run a SET PATH without it, and you kill your other paths...

```
SET PATH TO "X:\SomeShareOnServer\MyVFPDataPath\" ADDITIVE
```

Also, if you have any spaces in your path in question, MAKE SURE you use quotes around it, otherwise it will fail finding the path you expect and may cause compile error, such as

```
SET PATH TO X:\Some Share On Server\MyVFPDataPath\ ADDITIVE
```

Comment: As for a different opinion: while I'd say there is no perfect solution to VFP's path-handling peculiarities, `Set Path` can handle many paths better than `CurDir()` / "Start In" which can be only one, and the latter can be tampered with unintentionally by the end users or by buggy code not resetting `CurDir()`. And having different external files having the same name looks much more like an unusual exception to me than having several "paths" pointing to something like one or more folders containing DBC/DBF data, other ones external FRX reports, user-defined image files, FLL libraries etc.

Comment: @StefanWuebbe, agreed, it is a peculiar beast, but I have always prefered an explicit (pathVar + "theTable") so no ambiguities get in the way... Like you said, just another option/opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use VFP's `Set Path` command

```
Set Path To m.lcDataFolder
```

early in your client startup code, i.e. in your project's "main.PRG".
Where the content of the `m.lcDataFolder` could for example come from something like a custom "myConfig.XML/INI/TXT" containing the desired string, e.g. `\\fileServerNameOrIP\sharedDataFolder`

Answer (score 0):

Use 'SET DEFAULT TO' to change the current working directory or use explicit full paths as per the answer by @DRapp.